# Regex issue solving two conditions

Tags: python, regex

Here is the problem. I need to write a regex that highlights all of the items in the following text:

AAAAB

but not in this text:

ABABA

My first thought was to use `A?B?` but that didn't work. Any help/explanation would be much appreciated

Comment: What's the difference you would to handle between these texts?

Comment: There's not enough information to go on here, the regex string `"AAAAB"` will match the 1st but not the second, but you know that already. What's the pattern you're looking for? No B's following only a single A? `"A{2,}B"` Or something else?

Comment: Do you mean the regex should match at least 2 As followed by B? but not if no As are repeated? Please add more valid/invalid samples.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want to match only `AAAAB`, regardless of where it is relative to other text, then you could use the regular expression:

```
A{4}B
```

Here, `A` matchs the character A, `{4}` matches 4 of the preceding items (so in this case, the string AAAA) and `B` matches one occurrence of the character B, so long as it comes after the sequence of characters AAAA. This will not match the sequence `ABABA`.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is just that you want instances where A is repeated before B, that's easy enough:

```
import re
match = re.compile('AA+?B')
match.match('AAAAB') #Finds a match
match.match('ABAB') #Finds no match
```

If this isn't what you're looking for, you need to be more explicit about your expected output, and maybe give more examples.